# unable to run javac on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, javac

I'm trying to run javac on a Ubuntu terminal. But I get the following:

```
 $ javac
 The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.4-jdk
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * gcj-4.5-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

jdk is already installed and running `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk` says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 322 not upgraded.`

My jdk is installed in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-open-jdk; and I'm able to compile and run a java program from eclipse. But I'm having this fore-mentioned problem when using a terminal.

Comment: Is javac on your path? What output do you get from echo $PATH and echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: It does not appear on your path directly. In ubuntu there is a two-fold symlink (/usr/bin), first to /etc/alternatives/java, and from there to where it is actually located. if you echo $PATH, you will just get the regular binary directories like /usr/bin etc.

Comment: But if it's not on PATH I would be expecting something like "command not found".

Comment: Ubuntu tries to help you find the command if it isn't currently found.

Comment: As Dave Newton said, Ubuntu has a database of applications it knows about, you can have a look in the folder /usr/share/command-not-found if interested

Comment: Thanks Uku, that's useful to know.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `javac` binary (and probably other java binaries) is/are not in your user's `$PATH` environment variable. There are several ways you can address this:

1. Add `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-open-jdk/bin` to your user's `$PATH` environment variable. You can do this by adding a line similar to the following in your user's `.bash_profile`:

   `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-open-jdk/bin`

   You'll have to restart your terminal session for it to take effect.
2. Create symbolic links to the java binaries from some directory that's already part of your path (such as `/usr/bin`)

   `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-open-jdk/bin/java /usr/bin/`
   `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-open-jdk/bin/javac /usr/bin/`

   BTW: There are several other java executables in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-open-jdk/bin`. I've shown the symlink commands for `java` and `javac` above. You should run similar command for any other executables you may want to use.
3. Use the fully qualified path directly on the command line:

   `$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-open-jdk/bin/javac`

### Update:

Apparently, there is an elegant, but Ubuntu-specific solution to this problem. When on an Ubuntu system, use [update-java-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-java-alternatives.8.html).

Comment: Thank you. It fixed my problem. ;P It's weird though that it didn't say "command not found" in the first place.

Comment: Instead of creating the symbolic links by hand, you can just run `update-java-alternatives` to choose the implementation you want (java and javac may not be the only executables you need).

Comment: @Vincent Zoonekynd: Thanks for the tips. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you futher explain the Ubuntu-specific alternative? I'd love to run it! (Thanks for your help thus far too!)