# javac does not work in ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, javac

When I try to compile a java program with `javac`, I get an error:

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * gcj-4.7-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package
```

When I try java -version, it says,

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I try which java I get `/usr/bin/java`

How do I compile my java program from commandline?

Comment: Have you tried installing any of those packages?

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

Comment: What's up with -1 without comment?  What is the issue with this question?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As mentioned by @Blorgbeard you most likely do not have a Java JDK (Java Development Kit) installed.  See [this web page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) for more information about the various versions of Java available for Ubuntu.

The following command will install the OpenJDK version of the Java JDK:

```
apt-get install default-jdk
```

Comment: Perfect, after i ran above command given by @HeatfanJohn in ubuntu 12.10 for me javac, jps worked fine.

Comment: in ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 13):

I have Ubuntu 12.10, with java "1.6.0_27", this command makes javac available:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Then compile it like this:

```
el@apollo:~/retreat3$ javac HelloWorld.java
el@apollo:~/retreat3$ java HelloWorld
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had the JDK installed, but I'd installed it manually so it wasn't added to the path. Once I added these lines to my .zshrc file (I'm using zsh; if you're using bash, add them to .bash_profile) and relaunched the terminal, it worked:

```
# Java environment variables
export JAVA_HOME='/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_241'  #change accordingly; this needs to match your JDK's location!
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. I used the following command

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

The app compiled after that. Not sure what the difference is to the above solutions. Maybe I wouldn't of had to specify a version.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, java command was working on my ubuntu 16.04 but not javac.
At first, I fiddled around with the environment paths and all as i thought i had all java packages installed and the issue was with setting the environment path variable.

Then i tried the command `update-alternatives --list java`
which returned a path but  `update-alternatives --list javac` did not.
This explained to me that javac needed to be installed so I ran `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

But incase you get a path in running the `update-alternatives --list javac` then i suggest you should try setting up your $JAVA_PATH or creating symbolic links. Help to that can be found on the page [unable to run javac on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864612/unable-to-run-javac-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

**just copy and paste on your Terminal**

sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Fixed by installing OpenJDK 8 using Yum:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```