# which of these is my jdk version number?

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, version, javac

so I typed in `javac -version` into my terminal but I don't know which one is my JDK version number.

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste the content of your terminal into the post, as text. There's no need for an image here.

Comment: You seem not to have a jdk installed, so none of these are the version number. It's just a message telling you that the command `javac` doesn't exist and which packages contain such a command, so you can decide which one to install.

Comment: Looks like you need to install a jdk

Comment: It seems like you do not have the JDK installed, or at least the compiler (which is `javac`) is not on the PATH.

Comment: you don't have JDk installed. If you need to install `sudo apt-get default-jdk`

Comment: The OS is already suggesting you what to do.. just follow it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you clearly did not read the output you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out : [Java on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

Also, It does not look like you have it installed on your system. To install OpenJDK, run this command : 
    `apt-get install default-jdk`

To check if JDK is installed and running use `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`

Check the results, if you see that there are 0 installed and 0 upgrades, you may need to check the Java binary on your system.

A detailed step is mentioned here : [StackOverflow Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864612/unable-to-run-javac-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This error because of ***JAVA Not installed***  in your pc.

Follow this commands ***in order***

```
su -
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
exit
```

> ***Note:*** Some times when you run `su -` command in terminal its throw this kind of error **`su: Authentication failure`**. So then use **`sudo`** front of **`su -`** command. (Ex **`sudo su -`**)

and to check java version use `java` not `javac`

```
java -version
```

> **`javac`** is used with C Language